# Polya's Urn and Conditional Independence

Tags: markov-chains, polya-urn-model

We use the basic set up of Polya's Urn, with r red balls and b black balls. Let us then denote X<sub>n</sub> =1 if the ball picked is red and 0 if ball is black. Let us also denote S<sub>n</sub> = (X<sub>1</sub> +...+ X<sub>n</sub>)  to be the number of red balls picked up until time n.

I want to show that S<sub>n+1</sub> and S<sub>n-1</sub> are conditionally independent given S<sub>n</sub> for every n.

I realize this pertains to the Markov Property, and I can understand it intuitively, as we simply have to look at how many red balls we have now (at n), and then the value at n+1 is simply one jump away, however I am unsure how you would derive a formal proof.

Comment: Given $S_n$ there are only four possible states for $(S_{n-1},S_{n+1})$.  Just write them out and compute all the relevant probabilities by hand.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).